# Ubuntu got no .bash_login, .bash_profile

Tags: bashrc

I'm new to Ubuntu and currently on it for assignment

I need to run `source ~/.bashrc` at the first start of Ubuntu to enably my alias at the starting of the program.

I've checked that I need to modify the `.bash_login` or `.bash_profile` but when I checked with `ls -al`, I couldn't find both of the file, I got `.profile`, `.bash_logout`, `.bash_aliases`, and `.bash_history`

My question is, anything wrong with my system or it is hidden somewhere

A question aside, how can I start `source ~/.bashrc` at first run?

Comment: How did you create the user you're now using? The `.bashrc` file should be installed in the user's home directory (copied from `/etc/skel`), but this may be omitted if the user is created in an unusual way or marked as a system user for example.

Comment: There's only one user for now, which is me. "User created in an unusual way?" Possible? My /etc/skel has `.bash_login`, `.profile`, and `.bashrc`. And I'm running on Virtual Box not dual boot.

Comment: Again: How did you create that user? Was it already there after installation? If so, how did you install Ubuntu? Using a regular ISO or did you download a virtual appliance of some sort? We really need more information here. Also, the Bash system-wide configuration is here: `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which is being called for users without a `~/.bashrc` if I'm correct.

Comment: I'm using Virtual Box and during installation, Ubuntu ask for the user account. And that's where I created the account. I'm using the  Ubuntu 13.04 ISO file to install on VM.

Comment: @gertvdijk he never said he's missing `.bashrc`. He said he wants to run `source ~/.bashrc` upon login, and in order to do that, he read somewhere that he needs to add that command to `.bash_login` or `.bash_profile`, but he can't find those files. Right, @Unknown? You **can** see `.bashrc` in your home directory when you do `ls -al`, correct? You just can't find `.bash_login` and `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @Unknown `source ~/.bashrc` is already being called by default when booting. You'll see it being called by `.profile` (you'll see `. ~/.bashrc`, which is the same as `source ~/.bashrc`). Also, `.bashrc` then calls `.bash_aliases` if it exists, which is where you would put your aliases. Is this what you are seeking? Or did you put your aliases directly into `.bashrc`? It doesn't matter though, it'll still work.

Comment: @Alaa Uhm, read again. *"when I checked with ls -al, I couldn't find both of the file [...]"*

Comment: @gertvdijk Uhm, read again. Both of the files = `.bash_login` and `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @Alaa Yes, you're right. I've wrote my alias on `.bashrc` file and not into .bash_aliases file.But still the my alias doesn't work at during first start. It work when I manually type `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @qertvdijk I'm sorry if I didn't make my question clear. My both files is the `.bash_login` and `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Let's continue this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10332/discussion-between-alaa-and-unknown).